# Relating multiple names and values

Tags: phrases, nouns

I don't know why I have problem with saying a label:value consturction in English:

What should I write:

- In R2, **the attributes *tagName* and *className*** are used to identify the main article of the web page.
- In R2, **the *tagName* and *className* attributes** are used to identify the main article of the web page
- In R2, **the attributes of *tagName* and *className*** are used to identify the main article of the web page

Answer (score 1):

Either of the first two options you present are fine.

The third option wouldn't be used as you have written; the 'attributes of tagName' would mean that tagName is an object that **has** several attributes, but you haven't named those attributes.